# Submitting multiple dynamic forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to submit multiple forms at once when a single button is clicked. These forms are all generated automatically. They all have different action urls but the same id's. That's how the system (SaaS) works.

The problem is that I'm having issues getting the correct selectbox values and then send the forms. I'm not getting any error but I think it has something to do with identifiers. I'm working on this one for a few days now and I can't figure this one out.

So for every set/product there's some empty html, like so:

HTML

```
<div id="sets" class="clearfix">

 // first set
  <div class="set" data-handle="url" >
    <div class="right">
      <div class="products">
        <div class="close"></div>
        <div class="product">
          /// in here comes the product data from json ///
        </div>
        <div class="set-bestellen">
          <div class="link">
            <a title="add" class="trigger"><span>add to cart</span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- .products -->
    </div><!-- .right -->
    <div class="image"></div>
  </div>

 // second set
  <div class="set" data-handle="url" >
    <div class="right">
      <div class="products">
        <div class="close"></div>
        <div class="product">
          /// in here comes the product data from json ///
        </div>
        <div class="set-bestellen">
          <div class="link">
            <a title="add" class="trigger"><span>add to cart</span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- .products -->
    </div><!-- .right -->
    <div class="image"></div>
  </div>
// etc... can be as much as 10 sets

</div><!-- .#sets -->
```

Inside the above HTML `.product` there comes an automatically generated form. This form is generated like so:

Jquery

```
 $('#sets .set').each( function(){

    $(this).click(function(){

      if($(this).hasClass('open')){

        $('.close').click(function(){
          $('#sets .product').fadeOut();

          $('.products',this).animate({
            width: 'toggle'},500, function() {
             .......
            });
        });
      } else {

        .....

        }

        var url = $(this).data('handle')+'?format=json';

        $.getJSON(url, function (data){

          var product = data.product;

          var $container = $('.products .product');
          var productsHtml = [];

          var fullurl = 'http://www.shop.com';
          var variants = '';
          $.each(product.related, function(index, rel){
            var url = ''+fullurl+''+rel.url+'?format=json';

            ...... etc ...
            var productHtml = '<div id="'+rel.id+'" class="p"><form method="post" id="product_configure_form" action="http://www.shop.com/cart/add/'+rel.vid+'/" name="formsub"><div class="foto"><a href="'+fullurl+''+rel.url+'"><img class="rollover" src="'+image+'" hover="'+image2+'" alt="'+rel.fulltitle+'"/></a></div><div class="prijs" data-price="'+rel.price.price_incl+'">€'+rel.price.price_incl+'</div><div class="varianten_'+rel.id+'">';


            $.getJSON(url, function (data){
              var rel = data.product;

              var wqsSelectVariants = $('<div class="product-configure-variants tui" />');
              var select = $('<select id="product_configure_variants"/>');

              $.each(rel.variants, function (index, variant){
                select.append('<option value=' + variant.id + '>' + variant.title + '</option>');
                wqsSelectVariants.append(select);
              });
              $('.varianten_'+rel.id).html(wqsSelectVariants);
            });

            var price = rel.price.price_incl;
            sum += price;

            productHtml = productHtml + '</div></form></div>';
            productsHtml.push(productHtml);
          });
          $('.total').text('€'+sum.toFixed(2));
          productsHtml = productsHtml.join('')
          $container.html(productsHtml);
        });

      }      
    });

  });  

  etc.... 


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".trigger").on("click", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      $('form[name="formsub"]').each(function(){
        var variant = $('#product_configure_variants').val();

        var $form = $(this);

        $.ajax({
          type: $form.attr('method'),
          url: $form.attr('action')+variant+'/?quantity=1',
          data: $form.serialize(),
          success: function(data, status){
            if(status == 'success'){

            }else if(status == 'error'){

            }
          }
        });
      });


    });

  });
</script>
```

Does anyone know what's going wrong or give me some directions on how to fix that?

Comment: I'm not seeing any forms in that example link and clicking an image just takes me to that product's page without submitting any forms.

Comment: @ClaytonLeis: Yes sorry... corrected the link!

Comment: Step through your script and check if your form data is being built correctly.

Comment: I've removed a chunk of text from this question relating to a live description and a link that users could try when you asked the question. Since you'll presumably have fixed the problem shortly after receiving the answer, that link/material is not of help to future readers. For further questions, if you can try keeping the description in the question, and optionally in a pasteboard like JS Fiddle, it helps keep question illustrations working for future readers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$('form[name="formsub"]:visible')` as your selector. That should give you just the visible forms instead of all the ones on the page.

Comment: Ok that seems to work..thx! The problem that still is a problem... When triggering the button only the first product is added to cart. That's because the same `variant` is used twice. How can I get all `variants` for all forms? `each` doesn't do the trick..!